# jQuery .hide() works, but won't .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to make only one section be up at a time and while the other one is up the others are hidden. Let's say this is my HTML:

```
<a href="#about" class="text-center" title="">About</a>

<div class="about">
    <h2>About</h2>
</div>
```

And this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.about').hide();

    $('#about').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.about').show();
    });
});
```

The About section is hidden right away, however when I click on the About link, the About section does not show, or come back into view. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `$('#about')` you don't have any tag with the *ID* `about`

Comment: @wadie no, that element disappears, the ideal answer is to just give the `a` tag an id, since that's the `show/hide` trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put an id for the anchor element such as `id="about"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.about').hide();

    $('#about').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.about').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="about" href="#about" class="text-center" title="">About</a>

<div class="about">
    <h2>About</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forgot to add that into the anchor tag lol. Just a dumb mistake on my part :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the correct ID for the click event:

```
<a **id="about"** href="#about" class="text-center" title="">About</a>

<div class="about">
    <h2>About</h2>
</div>
```

Then this script will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.about').hide();

    $('#about').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.about').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

[you should put](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("a[href='#about']").on('click', function(e) {
...
```

or otherwise assign an id to element `a`.

```
<a href="#about" id="about" class="text-center" title="">About</a>
```

and then call it up with the [identity](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_id.asp) selector.

```
$('#about').on('click', function(e) {...
```